# How to visualize a multilevel/mixed model with two fixed effects and one random effect?

Tags: mixed-model, data-visualization, multilevel-analysis

The model I want to visualize is this one:

`BZ ~ 1 + SV_DMW + SV_DIFF (1 + SV_DMW| VPN)`

Do you have any ideas how to do this best?

This is how I visualized the model, where just SV_DMW was included.

[image]

The single lines are 5 random chosen subjects (VPN).

Do you have any idea how to visualize the model shown above similarly, or do you maybe have entirely different recommendations how to visualize the relationship?

Further information:
SV_DMW and BZ are, in general, associated positively
SV_DIFF and BZ are, in general, associated negatively

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What are these variables? It helps to have context, but, in particular, are SV_Diff and SV_DMV continuous or categorical or integers or what? Are they always positive?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @PeterFlom thanks for your questions. All variables are continuous. SV_Diff has a range from 1 to 6 and is associated negatively with BZ. SV_DMW has a range from 1 to 7 and is associted positively with BZ. BZ has a range from 1 to 9.
BZ = relationship satisfaction
SV_DMW = Jointly averaged level of sexual desire of a couple
SV_Diff = Difference of sexual desire of persons of a couple

Comment: Instead of plotting individuals, plot the predicted values.  Use two graphs. For graph 1, the x axis is SV_DIFF and the y axis is BZ. Make lines for different values of DMW (maybe the quartiles).  Graph 2, just the reverse.

Comment: Gelman's *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models* has many figures and visualizations wrt this class of models. Might be worth a look? https://www.google.com/books/edition/Data_Analysis_Using_Regression_and_Multi/lV3DIdV0F9AC?hl=en&gbpv=0

Answer (score 1):

The [sjPlot package](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/) can get you there. You can use the [`plot_model` function](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/reference/plot_model.html).

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
theme_set(theme_sjplot())

# Data creation inspired by Ben Bolker's post at 
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/38296264/7050882

set.seed(101)
SV_DMW = runif(6000, 1, 24)
SV_DIFF = runif(6000, 5, 15) * -SV_DMW
VPN = as.factor(rep(seq(1:60), each = 100))
testdata <- data.frame(SV_DMW, SV_DIFF, VPN)
testdata$BZ <- testdata$SV_DIFF * -testdata$SV_DMW/10 * rnorm(300, mean=30, sd=20)

# Model
fit = lmer(BZ ~ 1 + SV_DMW + SV_DIFF + (1|VPN),
           data = testdata, REML = TRUE)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("SV_DMW")) +
  ggtitle(element_blank()) +
  plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("SV_DIFF")) +
  ggtitle(element_blank())
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: linewidth
#> Ignoring unknown parameters: linewidth
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I simulated your data above. You can instead work directly on the `plot_model` part by replacing `fit` with the name of your model.